# tensorflow use all GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run my network on COCO2014(input images have shape `256, 256, 3`) using tf.data.Dataset, and have tensorflow session configured as follows

```py
sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                             inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                             allow_soft_placement=True)
sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
```

I spot this will always consume all my GPU memory(11G). I even tries to configure the session as follows

```py
sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                             inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                             allow_soft_placement=True)
sess_config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
sess = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
```

But still all GPU memory is used. Why would this happens? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Tensorflow use all GPU memory is that I use another temporary plain `tf.Session()`. Although this temporary session is closed immediately after it is used, Tensorflow does not free the GPU memory it allocates. Solution could be 1) do not use two sessions. 2) configure the temporary session as the one described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1) smaller memory footprint: 
`sess_config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1`

2) reducing the size of the image processed

`(256, 256, 3)` -> `(128, 128, 3)`